# `Cmd+shift+A` is not working, even in application `Key Codes`

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Not sure what has happened -- maybe I upgrade my mac to `10.10.4` -- I found my `cmd + shift + A` is not working any more.

I tried to use the application `Key codes` to show the keypress, and found the strange thing: If I press `cmd + shift + A`, the `A` will have none effect!

[image]

But if I press only `cmd + A`, or `shift + A`, the `A` is shown:

[image]

[image]

Where is wrong?

Comment: Cmd/shift/anything else works? (I can confirm I do see the A in Key Codes when I try it… not that that's any help;)

Comment: Any other chars with `cmd+shift` work, but `A`. Really strange

Comment: I'd try another keyboard - eliminate hardware/software

Comment: @Tetsujin Good suggestion, I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason.

I use the [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/) to set some global keyshort for some applications, and set `cmd + shift + a` to an application by mistake and later deleted that application. (But I totally forgot I have done this)

So for now, when I press `cmd + shift + a`, it captured by Apptivate, and which tries to call an non-existed application without any warning, and nothing happens on screen.

It's fixed when I removed that setting from Apptivate.